# HTML5 web storage abstraction libraries

Tags: html, local-storage, indexeddb, web-storage

From what I've read of web storage in HTML5, there are a number of different storage options with varying support across different browsers.

Are there any popular libraries for abstraction of web storage in HTML5 applications?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of YUI-based libraries for abstracting the underlying storage away:

- [YUI 2: Storage Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/)
- [YUI 3: Storage Lite](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/storage-lite)

You'd need to port them if you wanted to use them with another library, though it looks like someone has [already done that for jQuery](https://github.com/tarellel/jquery.Storage).